# Paste From MS Word to Redactor

Tags: redactor

Would I be right in assuming to allow clients to safely paste text from MS word into a WYSIWYG all I need to do is add:

```
pastePlainText: true
```

to my Redactor json config file? I have done this and it seems to be working but I am aware of the problems concerning MS Word and pasting to wysiwyg's and don't want to encounter them further down the track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't directly tried this myself, but I believe the answer is **yes, you are correct.**

To be fair, this is barely even a Craft question... This is 99% about Redactor, and what it is capable of. Skimming the [Settings > Clean](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean) page of the Redactor docs, it seems like Redactor already takes steps to normalize content from MS Word, and `pastePlainText` is simply one piece of the puzzle.

Here are some steps you can take to further assess whether you're getting the output you want from your Redactor settings...

- **Look at how the data is being stored in your database.** Specifically, keep an eye on your field's column in the `craft_content` table.
- **Try various settings from the [Redactor "Clean" options](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean)**. The developers behind Redactor are clearly aware of MS Word, and all of it's bizarre behavior. If you don't get the results you want right away, try mixing & matching Redactor settings until you get the desired behavior.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice buddy. I agree it is more of a Redactor question but still quite relevant to craft users who are trying to do the same thing. Thanks for the good answer :)

Comment: No problem! Agreed... even with the small direct relationship to Craft, it's a totally valid question and worth keeping around. :)